# Matlab, looking to place the next value from an array in the legend each time a loop executes

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to get the legend to show a fixed value and one that is from an array. I have managed to get the fixed value to display and when I manually enter the position from the array this will display. I want the position selected from the array to advance by 1 each time. I tried to use the n variable that I have defined in the script but it doesn't seem to work. At the moment I have entered a value of 4 and this selects the 4th value from the array. I am new to matlab and can't for the life of me think how to do this. Any help is appreciated. Here is my script I am working with.

```
clear
clc

f = @(x,k,lamda) ((lamda.^k).*(x.^(k-1)).*(exp(-lamda.*x))./(factorial(k-1)));

colors = ['k', 'r' , 'g', 'b', 'y', 'm', 'c'];

hold on
n=1;
k = 5;
x = 0 :0.1: 10;

for lamda = 1 : 0.2 : 2;

    ncol= mod(n,7)+1;
    plot(x,f(x,k,lamda), 'Color', colors(ncol))

    l = 1 : 0.2 : 2;

    legstr(n,:) = strcat ('k = ', num2str(k), '  Lamda = ', num2str (l(4)));

    legend(legstr)
    title('Erlang Distribution')
    xlabel('X')
    ylabel('f(x,k,lamda)')

    n=n+1;

end


hold off
```

Comment: I think you should be able to do just `strcat ('k = ', num2str(k), '  Lamda = ', num2str(lambda))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.  No need to introduce another vector to pull from since the value you have assigned to `lamda` in each loop iteration will work.  Also you'll have to change `legstr` from a matrix to a cell array to deal with the fact that `lamda` sometimes has an extra digit in the decimal place, which will cause the legend string to be longer or shorter, depending.

```
clear all
clc

f = @(x,k,lamda) ((lamda.^k).*(x.^(k-1)).*(exp(-lamda.*x))./(factorial(k-1)));

colors = ['k', 'r' , 'g', 'b', 'y', 'm', 'c'];

hold on
n=1;
k = 5;
x = 0 :0.1: 10;

for lamda = 1 : 0.2 : 2;

    ncol= mod(n,7)+1;
    plot(x,f(x,k,lamda), 'Color', colors(ncol))

%     l = 1 : 0.2 : 2;

    legstr{n} = strcat ('k = ', num2str(k), '  Lamda = ', num2str (lamda));

    legend(legstr)
    title('Erlang Distribution')
    xlabel('X')
    ylabel('f(x,k,lamda)')

    n=n+1;

end

hold off
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you have helped me immensely. I have been trying to solve this since lunch time today.

Comment: @CameronMacleod if this answer helped you please accept it by clicking the green tick mark at the top left. Thanks!